# Android display view buffer

Tags: android, view, buffer, surfaceview, pixelformat

I am working on a android application in which i need to send application view buffer to android (native) c file. Currently am doing it by creating bitmap of display view then make its buffer and pass it to native(.c) file. One important thing is that i need this view buffer in RGBA_4444 format. Please help me to do it by converting display view to Pixel-format RGBA_4444 and make its buffer without using bitmap.

My current code

```
screenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                mView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(screenBitmap);
        mView.layout(mView.getLeft(), mView.getTop(), mView.getRight(),
                mView.getBottom());

        mView.draw(mCanvas);
```

Comment: Where is the question?